# Expand Collapse DIV content using pure CSS or a combo of CSS and JS

Tags: html, css

I would like to implement a expand collapse action using pure CSS. The HTML looks like the below, where we can have many `expand-container` divs. The IDs are dynamic, so I don't want to rely on targeting IDs. I can't change the HTML to add checkboxes etc to maintain state, as it's coming from a server. So, would like to work with CSS only.

```
<div class="wikiContentBody">
   <div id="expander-1903026289" class="expand-container">
      <div id="expander-control-1903026289" class="expand-control">
         <span class="expand-control-icon">
         <img style="vertical-align:middle;" class="expand-control-image" 
            src="https://example.com/images/icons/grey_arrow_down.png">
         </span>
         <span class="expand-control-text">Problem Statement</span>
      </div>
      <div id="expander-content-1903026289" class="expand-content">
         <p>This content should be expandable and collapsible</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS I have so far:

```
.expand-control {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.expand-control:active ~ div.expand-content {
  display: block;
}
div.expand-content {
    display:none;
}
```

I am not sure if it's possible, but would also like to change the image source for `expand-control-image` from `https://example.com/images/icons/grey_arrow_down.png` to `https://example.com/images/icons/grey_arrow_up.png` , when the panel is expanded.

Comment: If what you wanted is to make it collapsible by clicking, then the short answer is **it's not possible**. In your example, you are using `:active` which only activates when the user is hold-clicking on it.

Comment: Is it possible to do it through JavaScript? I have this in an Angular app.

Comment: if using javascript, yes it would definitely be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use javascript or jQuery then you could toggle a class on the parent element:

```
$(".expand-control-icon").on("click", function(){
    $(".wikiContentBody").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Then in your CSS something like this:

```
.wikiContentBody.active div.expand-content {
  display: block;
}
```

As far as changing the img src via CSS what you could do is try wrapping the img in a div with position: relative. Then add a psuedo element with position: absolute and set the background-image to the secondary url you provided and set display: none. Once parent element has the class of active then display the pseudo element over the original image:

```
.expand-control-icon > div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.expand-control-icon > div::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("your other url");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
}


.wikiContentBody.active .expand-control-icon > div::after {
    display: block;
}
```

You might need to finesse it a little more than this, but could be a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you. I might need to do this using Vanilla JS than JQuery.. but will look into it..

Comment: This answer will cause confusion to other people who will stumble upon this question. The question specifically states "PURE CSS". Perhaps the OP should ask a new question that does not say pure css or rather update the question.

Comment: OP updated in his comments that javascript is a possible. Not sure why you downvote my answer when I have provided a solution to expanding/collapsing the div element that is pure CSS. The javascript functionality merely toggles a class while CSS does the rest of the work.

Comment: That's not pure css as it involves javascript.

Comment: Then it is the question itself and not the answer that should have been downvoted. I provided an answer based on the original criteria and the subsequent comment from the OP that stated that javascript was indeed a possibility